# How to check a checkbox with jQuery and by using Laravel variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I would like to know how to check the checkbox that is associated with the student found by my jQuery search function.To understand here is my "Ajax" request. Currently it displays the result of my search in a html 'span' but I just want to check the checkbox associated with the search.

This is my jQuery code where I do my request :

```
const { post } = require("jquery");

const form = document.getElementById('search-codebar-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
    const url = this.getAttribute('action');
    const q = document.getElementById('q').value;
   

    fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          q: q
        })
    }).then(response =>  {
        response.json().then (data => {

            // const newid = "student-${{id}}";

             document.getElementById(newid).checked = true;
            var data = {};
            data = "{{ $student->id }}";
    $("#student-.data").prop("checked", true); // And here I'm trying to take the id of the checkbox
 and check it.Watch out because the id change with the result because it is "student-{{ $student->id }}"
----------------------------------------------------------------
           // const etudiant = document.getElementById('etudiant');
            etudiant.innerHTML = '';


            Object.entries(data)[0][1].forEach(element =>{
               etudiant.innerHTML = `<span>${element.first_name}</span>`// At the moment
 I have this .So this empty my "div" and show the name of the result.
              
            });
        })
    }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error)
    })

});
```

And this is my form where this input is in my .blade
*The tag '' is much higher in my code but I just wanna show you the most important.*

```
<div id="etudiant">         
                  @foreach ($students as $student)
                   <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">                
                              <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                      {{$student->last_name}}
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                          {{$student->first_name}}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                          {{$student->uuid}}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">      
                             <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  name="students[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $student->id }}" id="student-{{ $student->id }}" />    
                            </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody> 
                   
                    @endforeach 
                       </div>
```

If you want more this is my Laravel controller associate to the request.

```
public function search_codebar(request $request): JsonResponse
    {

      $q = $request->input('q');

      $students = Student::where('uuid', 'like' ,$q )->get();

      return response()->json([
        "students" => $students]);
    }
    public function list_appel($id){
    return view('list_appel', ["appels" => Appel::all()]);
    
    }
```

So "q" in my jQuery code in define here to search the "uuid" of the student.
I hope you can understand what is my problem.
Thanks a lot !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eqcK.png

Answer (score 0):

`data = "{{ $student->id }}";`

does not seem to belong there. It is not part of the JavaScript and will be filled in when the page loads. That is unlikely what you want

IF your server returns JSON that contains an array of students and has the uuid, then you can do something like

```js
 }).then(response => response.json())
  .then (data => {
    data.forEach(student => $(`#student-${student.id}`).prop("checked", true))
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function (humhum). ```}).then(response =>  {
        response.json().then (data => {

             data.forEach((student) =>
                 $(`#student-${student.id}`).prop("checked", true)
             );
        })
    }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error)
    })

});```

Comment: But I still have an error ""TypeError: data.forEach is not a function"" which is an typo error.I use to modify the code and had a other error "Response null". 

My code now:

    }).then((response) => response.json).then((data) => {
            data.forEach((student) =>  //Open the loop //
                $(`#student-${student.UUID}`).prop("checked", true) //Find the id of the checkbox and check it//
            );
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

});

Thanks for the future help !

Comment: Object { students: (1) […] }
​students: Array [ {…} ]
0: Object { id: 1, uuid: "5667646090557", created_at: "2022-03-20T10:59:37.000000Z", … }
length: 1 <prototype>: Array [] <prototype>: Object { … } /This is the result of my research (I type the uuid of the student number 1

Comment: So change UUID to id in my code: `}).then(response => response.json())
  .then (data => {
    data.forEach(student => $(\`#student-${student.id}\`).prop("checked", true))`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :

```
.then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data)=>{
const students = data.students
students.forEach((student) => {
                $(`#student-${student.id}`).prop("checked", true)
            
            })

        })  
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
```

My data was an object and not an array !
So I had to use `.then((data)=>{ const students = data.students`

Comment: Nice, you turned this into a self-answer on your question. That is appreciated. (Sorry, for upvoting I lack the technical understanding. But take this as positive feedback for getting the idea of question and (self-)answer posts right, which takes many a new user some learning ...)